# JavaScript don't work while closing a tab in af:PanelTabbed

Tags: javascript, oracle-adf

Environment:

JDev Studio Edition Version 11.1.2.3.0

Component : PanelTabbed with ShowDetailItem

it is required to get clientListener while closing the ShowDetailItem from a PanelTabbed.
trying to create tabs dynamically using dynamicTabShell...!
can't use af:panelTabbed and showDetailItem component directly as using Oracle Dynamic Tabs Shell default implementation...

Frank posted a solution on blog...
https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/javascript_function_to_intercept_or

Don't know how to incorporate the clientListener with pageTemplate dynamicTabShell.jspx.

can't use <===>

```
<af:panelTabbed id="pt1" tabRemoval="all" >
<af:showDetailItem text="tabs" id="sdi1" disclosed="true" stretchChildren="first"
clientComponent="false">
<af:clientListener method="alertTabClose" type="item"/>
</af:showDetailItem>
</af:panelTabbed>

   function alertTabClose (closureEvent){
    var tab = closureEvent.getSource();  
    alert("test for TabClose event : ")
    ...
    }
```

<===>

In fact af:clientListener don't recognize **item** as one of the type of clientListener...

Any guess / help on this........???????

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
<af:clientListener method="alertTabClose" type="disclosure"/>
```

instead of

```
<af:clientListener method="alertTabClose" type="item"/>
```